# Deploy de aplicação no heroku dando erro

Tags: heroku

Sempre que eu tento dar deploy em uma aplicação no heroku, esse erro surge, não sei como consertá-lo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já testaste fazer login de novo na consola?

Comment: Sim, mas o erro persiste.

Answer (score 1):

O erro foi corrigido com o comando `git push heroku master -f`